# PyQt5/qml app crashes when using python lock on a qml object

Tags: crash, pyqt5, segmentation-fault, qml, locking

i have a PyQt/qml app that crashes randomly and i cant figure why.

environment:
PyQt: 5.9.2
python: 3.6.9
ubuntu 18.04.6

what im doing is:

- sending a dict to qml with a pyqtsignal
- adding an item to a ListModel thats built from this dict
- using model.get(0) to get this item back and send the model item to python side with a pyqtslot
- on python side saving this item in a dict {id: qml_object}
- update this qml item with setProperty()
- while im updating the qml object im using a python threading.lock around it so the same object wont be updated twice

this process sometimes crashes with a segmentation fault and i dont understand why, i know its a weird way to implement it but i want to update the qml objects quickly and using setProperty from python side looks like the quickest way to go (instead of sending a signal to qml and search for the specific object)

main.py

```
class MyApp(QApplication):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyApp, self).__init__(sys.argv)
    self.manager = Manager()
    self._engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    self._engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("manager", self.Manager())
    self._engine.load("main.qml")
```

manager.py

```
class Manager(QObject):
insertObject = pyqtSignal(QVariant, arguments=["dict"])

def __init__(self):
    QObject.__init__(self)
    self.qml_objects = {}
    self.lock = Lock()
    self.insertObject.emit({"name": "aaa"})


# something that triggers update_qml_object

def update_qml_object(self, obj_id, name):
    with self.lock:
        self.qml_objects[obj_id].setProperty("name", name)

@pyqtSlot(str, QVariant, name="setQmlObject")
def set_event_qml_object(self, id, event_qml_obj):
    self.qml_objects[id] = event_qml_obj

@pyqtSlot(str, QVariant, name="setQmlObject")
def set_event_qml_object(self, id, event_qml_obj):
    self.qml_objects[id] = event_qml_obj
```

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
Item {
    ListModel {
        id: gridModel
        ...
    }

    listView{
        ....
    }

    Connections {
        target: manager
        onInsertObject: {
            addObj(dict)
        }
    }

    function addObj(obj) {
        model.add_item({"name": obj.name})
        manager.setQmlObject(0, model.get(0))
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Using a `Lock` is wrong and pointless. Within a thread (and, in this case, the main thread) there is no risk of concurrency, as all functions are called synchronously: `update_qml_object` will never get called *again* while the previous call has not returned yet. That said, knowing what will actually call `update_qml_object` would help us understand what you are doing and if there's really a requirement for such "lock" (which can be achieved with a simple bool flag, by the way).

Comment: Following up to what @musicamante is indicating, if you are indeed using threads and we just don't see that code here, please note that only the main thread should ever make calls to QML. Most all GUI toolkits are *not* thread-safe and cannot be called from multiple threads.

Comment: well the update_qml_object is indeed called from the main thread but with the help of QTimer.singleshot which from my understanding doesn't use a separate thread